# curses in python getstr() while refreshing

Tags: python, ncurses, curses

I am  writing a front end for a server application using the curses module. THe main windows returned by curses is divided into 2 sub-windows.  The top half of the screen prints output from the server while the bottom line takes input with window.getstr(). Sometimes when I am entering text and the top half is updating the whole screen goes crazy with random characters replacing the existing characters. Is there a specific cause for this or is it a curses bug?

Comment: I was thinking of implementing something like this, but losing the ability to scroll back through the server output would be unacceptable. I wonder if there's a way to preserve that functionality in curses...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing you are using a thread to update the upper display while window.getstr() runs in the main thread?

If so, the problem is that the curses terminal state is a shared resource that can't be updated from two different threads simultaneously. You need to put the terminal into non-blocking mode, use window.getch() to build up an input string and have your thread pass the upper window update task to the main thread.

Comment: I figured it was something like that, but didn't want to re-factor it if i didn't have t