# Threading with Python Curses giving me weird characters?

Tags: python, multithreading, curses

Hey there Stack Overflow. I'm trying to build a testing script that should mix outputting changing characters (using curses) on multiple lines (creating them over time), creating new lines based on the thread number. 
I have the below code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import curses, time, threading

def threadedFunction(linePos):
    stdscr = curses.initscr()
    curses.noecho()
    curses.cbreak()

    try:
        stdscr.clear()
        for i in range(50):
            stdscr.addstr(linePos, 0, "testing %s..." % i)
            stdscr.refresh()
            time.sleep(.1)
    finally:
        curses.echo()
        curses.nocbreak()
        curses.endwin()
        pass
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    for x in xrange(0, 4): # should produce 5 lines maximum
        exec("process" + str(x) + " = threading.Thread(target = threadedFunction, args = (" + str(x) + ",))")
        exec("process" + str(x) + ".start()")
```

I tried using the `multithreading` library before, but I had no hope with it. The threading library at least will display the numbers I want on a few lines before it goes crazy. Here's an example of what it does when I run it:

[image: Testing Python Curses with (incremental) Threading]

All I want is for the program to just simply start a new thread, and display a line that counts to 50 while adding new lines doing the same thing. How would I go about doing this?? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Just a thought, and I am not familiar with stdscr stuff, but at this line stdscr.addstr(linePos, 0, "testing %s..." % i) you don't call str(i). Have you tried it that way?

Comment: @Jeff yeah I have and it doesn't change anything; still get errors unfortunately.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [curses in python getstr() while refreshing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8569878/curses-in-python-getstr-while-refreshing)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Workaround for ncurses multi-thread read and write](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53809310/workaround-for-ncurses-multi-thread-read-and-write)

Answer (score 0):

Printing to the terminal from multiple threads will give you intermingled output like that. It is a very simple example of [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition). Use some kind of locking mechanism to coordinate writes to the terminal, or make sure to only write from one thread (for example, using a FIFO to pass message to the writing thread, which will write them to the terminal).

The weird numbers you see are part of the [ANSI escape sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Escape_sequences) that are used by programs to use special features of the terminal: writing `\x1B[nF` to the output will make your terminal move the cursor one line up, for example. Curses is outputting such codes for you, and because the terminal interprets them according to the ANSI meaning, you don't usually see them. But because of the multithreading issue, those become mingled and invalid, and part of them get printed to the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you only use curses in one thread, other processing-heavy threads can disrupt the escape sequences in the curses thread.  The environment variable `$ESCDELAY` indicates how long (in ms) to wait after an escape code (0x1B) is sent; and if more than that time elapsed, a `^[` keystroke (ESC) is returned by get_wch().

Comment: However, OP is using multiple threads, so this answer is not useful.

Answer (score 0):

Use `stdscr.noutrefresh()` instead of `stdscr.refresh()`, then call `curses.doupdate()` in a designated thread that handles the update. The idea is to do `curses.doupdate()` only in one thread.