# getting rid of control character with ncurses and threaded class

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to develop some kind of terminal user interface in python3
with threading and ncurse and some weird characters appear.

Based on the answer in this post:

[Threading with Python Curses giving me weird characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46773577/threading-with-python-curses-giving-me-weird-characters/55306004#55306004)

which is exactly my problem, i tried to implement locking the maj() function  (and also tested with rlock) in my code .
But it seams the lock does not block other thread .
Is my lock misplaced ?? or am i hitting a technical limit ?

here after is an example my code :

```
import threading
from time import sleep
import curses
import logging
from curses.textpad import Textbox, rectangle
from datetime import datetime

class GenericTUI(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self,textmode=False, messageBoxSize=10, logger=logging.getLogger()):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.keyPressedList = list()
        self.alive = True
        self.myStdscr = None
        self.title = ""
        self.messageList = list()
        self.messageBoxSize = messageBoxSize
        self.subTitle = ""
        self.priceInfo = ""
        self.progInfo = ""
        self.textMode = textmode
        self.logger = logger
        self.lock = threading.Lock()


    def run(self):
        if self.textMode :
            with open('/tmp/genericTUI.command','w+') as f:
                # command file in text mode
                pass
            while self.alive :
                print("Program :"+ self.title)
                print("sub"+self.subTitle)
                print("Prices : "+self.priceInfo)
                print("ProgInfos :"+self.progInfo)
                for m in self.messageList :
                    print(m)
                with open('/tmp/genericTUI.command','r+') as f:
                    c = f.read(1)
                    if  c:
                        self.keyPressedList.append(c)
                        f.truncate(0)
                sleep(5)
        else :        
            curses.wrapper(self.main)

    def maj(self):
        '''
        mise a jour de l ecran
        au sujet du thread lock :
        https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46773577/threading-with-python-curses-giving-me-weird-characters
        '''
        # determine la taille de  l ecran
        max_y, max_x = self.myStdscr.getmaxyx() 
        # reecriture

        with self.lock :
            try :
                self.myStdscr.clear()
                for x in range(max_x):
                    self.myStdscr.addch(0,x,curses.ACS_HLINE)
                self.myStdscr.addstr(1, 2, "Program :"+ self.title, curses.color_pair(1) )
                self.myStdscr.addstr(2, 2,  self.subTitle)
                for x in range(max_x):
                    self.myStdscr.addch(3,x,curses.ACS_HLINE)
                self.myStdscr.addstr(4, 2, "Prices : "+self.priceInfo, curses.color_pair(2))
                for x in range(max_x):
                    self.myStdscr.addch(5,x,curses.ACS_HLINE)
                self.myStdscr.addstr(6, 2, "ProgInfos :"+self.progInfo, curses.color_pair(5))
                for x in range(max_x):
                    self.myStdscr.addch(7,x,curses.ACS_HLINE)
                indent =0 
                for m in self.messageList :
                    self.myStdscr.addstr(8+indent, 3,m)
                    indent+=1
                for y in range(max_y):
                    self.myStdscr.addch(y,0,curses.ACS_VLINE)

                self.myStdscr.refresh()
            except Exception as e:
                self.logger.error(repr(e))
                self.myStdscr.clear()


    def main(self,stdscr):   
        # color definition
        if curses.has_colors():
            curses.start_color()
            curses.init_pair(1, curses.COLOR_WHITE, curses.COLOR_BLUE)
            curses.init_pair(2, curses.COLOR_WHITE, curses.COLOR_RED)
            curses.init_pair(3, curses.COLOR_WHITE, curses.COLOR_YELLOW)
            curses.init_pair(4, curses.COLOR_BLACK, curses.COLOR_BLUE)
            curses.init_pair(5, curses.COLOR_BLACK, curses.COLOR_GREEN)

        ## NE SURTOUT PAS METTRE keypad(false) GENERE DES CARACTERES AU HASARD .. DANGEREUX
        self.myStdscr = stdscr
        self.myStdscr.nodelay(True)
        self.myStdscr.keypad(True)
        self.myStdscr.box()

        counter = 0
        while self.alive:
            try : 
                key =  self.myStdscr.getkey()
                self.keyPressedList.append(key)
            except Exception as e:
                ## le nodelay rend l interface reactive mais ,le getkey genere un noinput error
                ## si pas de touche pressée d ou le pass 
                pass

            sleep(0.1)
            counter +=1

    def getKeyPressed(self):
        if self.keyPressedList :
            return self.keyPressedList.pop()
        else :
            return None

    def stop(self):
        self.alive = False

    def updatePriceInfo(self,priceDict,maj=False):
        result = " ".join(str(key) +":"+ str(value)+"|" for key, value in priceDict.items())
        self.priceInfo = result
        if maj :
            self.maj()

    def updateTitle(self,title, maj=False):
        self.title = str(title)
        if maj :
            self.maj()


    def updateSubTitle(self,subtitleDict, maj=False):
        result = " ".join(str(key) +":"+ str(value)+"|" for key, value in subtitleDict.items())
        self.subTitle = str(result)
        if maj :
            self.maj()


    def updateProgInfo(self,messDict, maj=False):
        result = " ".join(str(key) +":"+ str(value)+"|" for key, value in messDict.items())
        self.progInfo = result
        if maj :
            self.maj()


    def addMessage(self,mess, maj=False):
        self.messageList.append(repr(mess))
        if len(self.messageList) > self.messageBoxSize : self.messageList.pop(0)
        if maj :
            self.maj()


    def getValue(self, mess="Enter Value: (hit Ctrl-G to send)"):
        self.myStdscr.addstr(0, 0, mess)

        editwin = curses.newwin(1,7, 2,1)
        rectangle(self.myStdscr, 1,0, 1+1+1, 1+7+1)
        self.myStdscr.refresh()
        box = Textbox(editwin)
        box.stripspaces = True

        # Let the user edit until Ctrl-G is struck.
        box.edit()

        # Get resulting contents
        return(box.gather().strip())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ## the main is used for some test when the lib is called directly
    testGUI = GenericTUI()
    alive = True
    testGUI.logger.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler())
    testGUI.logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    testGUI.start()
    while alive :
        testGUI.updateTitle('time %s'%str(datetime.now() ))
        k = testGUI.getKeyPressed()
        if k is not None:
            if k=='Q' :
                alive = False
            elif k=='M' :
                mess = testGUI.getValue()
                testGUI.addMessage(mess,maj=True)
            else :
                testGUI.addMessage('unknown key %s'%k , maj=True)
        sleep(0.1)
    testGUI.stop()
```

as you can see there is a with self.lock statement in the maj()function o the class, but 
in my log i still get a lot of errors like :
alphanumeric key ? pressed
unknown key press : ?
alphanumeric key [ pressed
unknown key press : [
alphanumeric key  pressed
unknown key press : 
alphanumeric key ? pressed

where should i place my lock to avoid that ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answer my own question, but I think it will be hepfull for others :
The trick is in the ncurses wrapper which have is own thread . So If i want the lock to work I have to put it in the main loop . 
Below is the code modified  :

````
import threading
from time import sleep
import curses
import logging
from curses.textpad import Textbox, rectangle
from datetime import datetime
import re

class GenericTUI(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self,textmode=False, messageBoxSize=10, logger=logging.getLogger()):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.keyPressedList = list()
        self.alive = True
        self.myStdscr = None
        self.title = ""
        self.messageList = list()
        self.messageBoxSize = messageBoxSize
        self.subTitle = ""
        self.priceInfo = ""
        self.progInfo = ""
        self.textMode = textmode
        self.logger = logger
        self.lock = threading.Lock()
        self.refreshFlag = True


    def run(self):
        if self.textMode :
            with open('/tmp/genericTUI.command','w+') as f:
                # command file in text mode
                pass
            while self.alive :
                print("Program :"+ self.title)
                print("sub"+self.subTitle)
                print("Prices : "+self.priceInfo)
                print("ProgInfos :"+self.progInfo)
                for m in self.messageList :
                    print(m)
                with open('/tmp/genericTUI.command','r+') as f:
                    c = f.read(1)
                    if  c:
                        self.keyPressedList.append(c)
                        f.truncate(0)
                sleep(5)
        else :        
            curses.wrapper(self.main)


    def main(self,stdscr):   
        # color definition
        if curses.has_colors():
            curses.start_color()
            curses.init_pair(1, curses.COLOR_WHITE, curses.COLOR_BLUE)
            curses.init_pair(2, curses.COLOR_WHITE, curses.COLOR_RED)
            curses.init_pair(3, curses.COLOR_WHITE, curses.COLOR_YELLOW)
            curses.init_pair(4, curses.COLOR_BLACK, curses.COLOR_BLUE)
            curses.init_pair(5, curses.COLOR_BLACK, curses.COLOR_GREEN)

        ## NE SURTOUT PAS METTRE keypad(false) GENERE DES CARACTERES AU HASARD .. DANGEREUX
        self.myStdscr = stdscr
        self.myStdscr.nodelay(True)
        self.myStdscr.keypad(True)
        self.myStdscr.box()

        counter = 0
        while self.alive:
            try : 
                key =  self.myStdscr.getkey()
                #workaround to avoid multi thread escape character
                if re.match('[A-Z_\+\-\*/]', key) :
                    self.keyPressedList.append(key)
            except Exception as e:
                ## le nodelay rend l interface reactive mais ,le getkey genere un noinput error
                ## si pas de touche pressée d ou le pass 
                pass
            '''    
            screen update in the mail loop
            to be able to thread lock :
            https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46773577/threading-with-python-curses-giving-me-weird-characters
            '''
            # determine la taille de  l ecran
            max_y, max_x = self.myStdscr.getmaxyx() 
            # reecriture
            if self.refreshFlag:
                try :
                    with self.lock :
                        self.myStdscr.clear()
                        for x in range(max_x):
                            self.myStdscr.addch(0,x,curses.ACS_HLINE)
                        self.myStdscr.addstr(1, 2, "Program :"+ self.title, curses.color_pair(1) )
                        self.myStdscr.addstr(2, 2,  self.subTitle)
                        for x in range(max_x):
                            self.myStdscr.addch(3,x,curses.ACS_HLINE)
                        self.myStdscr.addstr(4, 2, "Prices : "+self.priceInfo, curses.color_pair(2))
                        for x in range(max_x):
                            self.myStdscr.addch(5,x,curses.ACS_HLINE)
                        self.myStdscr.addstr(6, 2, "ProgInfos :"+self.progInfo, curses.color_pair(5))
                        for x in range(max_x):
                            self.myStdscr.addch(7,x,curses.ACS_HLINE)
                        indent =0 
                        for m in self.messageList :
                            self.myStdscr.addstr(8+indent, 3,m)
                            indent+=1
                        for y in range(max_y):
                            self.myStdscr.addch(y,0,curses.ACS_VLINE)

                        self.myStdscr.refresh()
                except Exception as e:
                    self.logger.error(repr(e))
                    self.myStdscr.clear()
                finally: 
                    self.refreshFlag = False

            sleep(0.1)
            counter +=1

    def getKeyPressed(self):
        if self.keyPressedList :
            return self.keyPressedList.pop()
        else :
            return None

    def stop(self):
        self.alive = False

    def updatePriceInfo(self,priceDict,maj=False):
        result = " ".join(str(key) +":"+ str(value)+"|" for key, value in priceDict.items())
        self.priceInfo = result
        self.refreshFlag = maj


    def updateTitle(self,title, maj=False):
        self.title = str(title)
        self.refreshFlag = maj


    def updateSubTitle(self,subtitleDict, maj=False):
        result = " ".join(str(key) +":"+ str(value)+"|" for key, value in subtitleDict.items())
        self.subTitle = str(result)
        self.refreshFlag = maj

    def updateProgInfo(self,messDict, maj=False):
        result = " ".join(str(key) +":"+ str(value)+"|" for key, value in messDict.items())
        self.progInfo = result
        self.refreshFlag = maj

    def addMessage(self,mess, maj=False):
        self.messageList.append(repr(mess))
        if len(self.messageList) > self.messageBoxSize : self.messageList.pop(0)
        self.refreshFlag = maj

    def getValue(self, mess="Enter Value: (hit Ctrl-G to send)"):
        with self.lock :
            self.myStdscr.addstr(0, 0, mess)

            editwin = curses.newwin(1,7, 2,1)
            rectangle(self.myStdscr, 1,0, 1+1+1, 1+7+1)
            box = Textbox(editwin)
            box.stripspaces = True
            self.myStdscr.refresh()
            # Let the user edit until Ctrl-G is struck.
            box.edit()

        # Get resulting contents
        return(box.gather().strip())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ## the main is used for some test when the lib is called directly
    testGUI = GenericTUI()
    alive = True
    testGUI.logger.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler())
    testGUI.logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    testGUI.start()
    while alive :
        testGUI.updateTitle('time %s'%str(datetime.now() ))
        k = testGUI.getKeyPressed()
        if k is not None:
            if k=='Q' :
                alive = False
            elif k=='M' :
                mess = testGUI.getValue()
                testGUI.addMessage(mess,maj=True)
            else :
                testGUI.addMessage('unknown key %s'%k , maj=True)
        sleep(0.1)
    testGUI.stop()
    ```
you may also notice there is another lock in the getvalue function to avoid the main thread to erase the textbox .

Hope this help others.
````